# Can't use public class in my web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, vs-web-site-project

Why i can't use the following public class :

```
namespace OrganizerUI.App_code
{
    public class Employee
    {

        private string text;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { text = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

---

in my `web service` :

[image]

Comment: do you add using OrganizerUI.App_code in webservice ?

Comment: Is your web service code file set to compile? By default, code added to the App_Code folder is set to "content" rather than "compile". Right-click file, get properties and check.

Comment: rebuild the solution...may references   are not updated.

Comment: @Lukos: Thanks a lot it works now ,Could u write it as an  answer so can i confirm it

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @John Saunders: Could u tell me if they are used with the same steps or there are some differences ?

Comment: If there were no differences, then they would be the same thing. The steps are similar for similar scenarios. WCF has maybe 100 times the functionality of ASMX, so, naturally, it's different. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info for a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often (always?), code files that are added to the Visual Studio App_Code directory are not set by default to compile even if they are .Net code. They are set to "Content" which means they are included in the output only. If you right-click the file and choose "properties" you can see/change it to "compile" instead of "content".