# script not working in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

im using script to bind my dropdown in my mvc project using web service and my webservice is present inside app_code but its not calling and error is called in my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json,charset=utf-8",
    url: "/App_Code/WebService1.asmx.cs/loadcountry",
    data: "{}",
    datatype: "json",
    sucess: function (Result) {
        alert("s");
        $("#country").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("Select Country"));
        $("#state").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("Select State"));
        $each(Result.d, function () {
            $("#country").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    },
    error: function (Result) {
        alert("1");
    }
});
});
```

can anyone tell me where im going worng  , thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you visit /App_Code/WebService1.asmx.cs/loadcountry directly?

Comment: @Tokn when page loads alert 1 is shown without going to that page so i dont know where im wrong

Comment: Open up a rest client and POST to  /App_Code/WebService1.asmx.cs/loadcountry . What happens?

Comment: server showing  The address wasn't understood  @Tokn

Comment: So are you sure your webservice actually works and accepts POSTs?

Comment: yes but how to call the method in webservice @Tokn

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL property by:

```
url: "~/App_Code/WebService1.asmx/loadcountry"
```

Edit:

And `sucess` by `success` (as Dethariel says in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Can this be a misspelling on the line `sucess` (should be `success` - double `c`)?

Comment: @dazzlingkumar Make sure you keep it as 'success' though, don't change it back to 'sucess'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a few problems in your call, the first one is the metioned by [Opec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544900/1322417)

And the other one is where you create the web service, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226215/1322417) tell you why.

I recommend you that put your web services in the project root or in another folder. And then change your call to something like this:

```
url: "~/MyNewFolder/WebService1.asmx/loadcountry"
```

Comment: Ok, but what's say the error message? I mean, could you post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change url to call WebService1.asmx, not WebService1.asmx.cs
2. loadcountry. Does it has WebMethod attribute?
3. According to the name loadcountry I suppose it should be GET method, not POST.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess but I reckon you need a 'GET' instead of a 'POST'. It looks to me like your webservice is simply providing a list of countries and doesn't accept any data posted to it.

You can test your webservice in a rest client like Chrome's Advanced Rest Client